# Is command arp-scan working with loopback?

Tags: command-line, networking, ethernet, scanner

Apparently command arp-scan is working with eth0 like :

> sudo arp-scan –I eth0 -l

But this happens, when system is set-up with loopback :

> sudo arp-scan --interface=lo --localnet

Delivers output :

> [sudo] password für $user:
>
> Interface: lo, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
>
> Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 16777216 hosts (http://www.nta-
>
> monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)

Why are here over 16 Million hosts scanned off each other one by one ?
I did not intend that to sit directly at provider, while using command arp-scan ?

How can I limit 16 Mio hosts to just the recent 2.000 hosts ?

Answer (score 0):

By using `--localnet` option of `arp-scan`, the hosts to scan are derived from the subnet configuration of the interface specified.

In your case, thats `lo` with a `127.0.0.1/8` address and subnet, which results in 16777216 possible addresses.
According to the man page of `arp-scan`, you can limit the amount of targets either by adding them on the commandline or make use of the `--file` option.

By the way, I don't think it makes a lot sense to `arp-scan` your loopback device.

Comment: Yes I see, when I put in a certain ip-range with lower and upper ip-address, then arp-scan is breaking off the scan. I think it has to do with the firewall of the provider. True - it then makes no sense.